# Testing if object has multiple properties

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm having trouble checking this object is there something I need to do to chain multiple `.to.have.property` statements? I believe I'm just returning the result from the last `.to.have.property` into the next one.

```
expect(shopify.formatRequestOptions("shop"))
  .to.have.property('url', "https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")
  .to.have.property('method', "GET")
  .to.have.deep.property('headers.X-Shopify-Access-Token', settings.accessToken)
```

It seems I can use something like this [chai-subset](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-subset) to check an object. Is there no way to chain these together? I'd hate to have to do this.

```
var result = shopify.formatRequestOptions("shop")
expect(result).to.have.property('url', "https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json")
expect(result).to.have.property('method', "GET")
expect(result).to.have.deep.property('headers.X-Shopify-Access-Token', settings.accessToken)
```

Comment: I don't know much about it, but it looks like that is work in progress. See link https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could build your own function that just returns `true` / `false` and has any interface.

```
let example = {
  'name': 'thomas'
}

let hasAllProps = (obj, props) => {
  let propsTrue = _.chain(props)
  .map(prop => _.has(obj, prop))
  .without(false)
  .value()
  return (propsTrue.length === props.length)
}

console.log(hasAllProps(example, ['name'])) // true
console.log(hasAllProps(example, ['age'])) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `nested.includes`.

```
var result = shopify.formatRequestOptions("shop")
expect(result).to.nested.include({
    url: "https://"+settings.shop+"/admin/shop.json"
    method: 'GET',
    'headers.X-Shopify-Access-Token': settings.accessToken // this where nested kicks in, on the dot path
});
```